# Codeigniter : How to join 2 tables in databases from 2 different connections

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I made two database connections in `database.php`, one for reading which is my localhost machine and one for writing "insert" which is an online database.

But I ran into this problem when I wanted to join the two tables "answers" in the localhost database and "user" in the online database.

```
    function get_users() {
    $write_db   = $this->load->database('default', TRUE); /* database conection for localhost DB */
    $read_db    = $this->load->database('read', TRUE); /* database conection for online DB */

    $read_db->select('*');
    $read_db->from('ibitstore.user');
    $write_db->join('english.answers','ibitstore.user.user_id = english.answers.user_id');
    $query = $read_db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query->result_array();

    return array();
}
```

When I use `$write_db` with the join clause

> ```
>   $write_db->join('english.answers','ibitstore.user.user_id = english.answers.user_id');
> ```

data is retrieved from the online database but not from the localhost database, like it ignored the join I tried to use:

`$read_db->join('english.answers','ibitstore.user.user_id = english.answers.user_id');`

Then I got this SQL error. Looks like it thought that the "answers" table is on the online DB:

```
A Database Error Occurred
```

Error Number: 1142

SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'49.32.197.240' for table 'answers'

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ibitstore`.`user`)
  JOIN `english`.`answers`
    ON `ibitstore`.`user`.`user_id` = `english`.`answers`.`user_id`
```

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\english\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Please Help :(

Comment: I don't think databases allow cross-connection joins.

Comment: the problem is that you dont have right access one database from them that's why it is producing error. If you allow used to access database you can work with your approach. It is fine. No problem

Answer (score 0):

You only have one connection to a database at a time. You'd have to run a query on one database, run a query on the second database and then manipulate the results of both within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can run one SQL Query to be executed on two or more different databases.  Containing tables of each.
 How ever you can get the data from one database then use your own logic to merge them.